# Alignements of items inside a flex container

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

In the design model that I have, I have two types of design to implement for my header:

- One with just a centered label and the logo to its left
- Another one with a centered label, with a logo to its left and a button on the right of the page

I thought I'd use a flex container for the whole header  and then inside this, nested flex items.
My main problem for the first case is that I can't figure out a simple way to keep the title dead centered and have a logo on the left, even though that sounds very basic to accomplish. My second problem is that with the `margin-left: auto`/`margin-right: auto` approach, my logo is not kept close to my title if I enlarge the page width.

For the second use case, I divided the header in 3 parts with `flex: 1` on the left and right part, along with a `justify-content: flex-end`. But there might be a cleaner way to do it.

Here is where I am at right now

**HTML**

```
<section class="brands">
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <icon-base
      class="header__icon"
      width="46"
      height="46"
      icon-name="brands"
    >
      <brands />
    </icon-base>
  </div>
  <div class="header__middle">
    <h2 class="header__text">Brand App</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right"></div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.brands {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: $l-size $m-size;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  display: flex;

  > * {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  &__left {
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &__right {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you were to add the code you already tried

Comment: Edited my post!

Comment: When you're dealing with a positive space case (which seems to be your case), in order to *"dead center"* a flex item into a flex container left and right sides need to be pushing against it with equal weight. That's the only way. The *weight* is determined primarily by `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` attributes of elements on its sides, but the `flex-basis` can be influenced by `width`, `max-width` and `min-width` attributes (in your case, or `height` if it was on the other direction). When dealing with negative space cases, it's `flex-shrink` that counts, not `flex-grow`.

Comment: Here's an example on how to achieve equal flexbox weight (centering) on variable content sides: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/f3746myk/ Perhaps not obvious, but the centering depends on `flex-basis: 0%`.

Comment: What if there's no lorem ipsum text and I want to maintain that width ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Using Flexbox**

I would only apply `flex: 1` on `.header__left` and `.header__right` so that they can take up equal amounts of the available space inside of `.header` while `.header__middle` shrinks down to its content's width.

Then, you can use `justify-content: flex-end` on `.header__left` to ensure the left icon is always close to the brand logo.

**SCSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    display: flex;

    &__left,
    &__right {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    &__left {
        background: orange;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        /* You can either apply padding to .header__left or 
           .header__middle to separate the icon from the 
           brand logo. */
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }
    &__middle {
        background: green;

        /* This isn't really needed since this container's 
           column width is set to auto. */
        justify-content: center;
    }
    &__right {
        background: red;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header__icon {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    background: blue;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
}

.header__left,
.header__right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__left {
  background: orange;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.header__middle {
  background: green;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__right {
  background: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__icon {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <icon-base class="header__icon" width="46" height="46" icon-name="brands">
      <brands />
    </icon-base>
  </div>
  <div class="header__middle">
    <h2 class="header__text">Brand App</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <button>Some button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

To hide the right-aligned button, I would use `visibility: hidden` on `.header__right`. This ensures that `.header__right` still takes up space in the layout but isn't visible or interactive.

Using `display: none` or removing the HTML element completely will not work with this approach since this will remove the element from the layout. As a result, `.header__left`, which has `flex: 1`, will take up the entire available space in the header, including the space previously occupied by `.header__right`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khan_y/o6qL2smz/5/)

---

> **Using CSS grids**

Another approach would be to use `display: grid` on `.header` and use `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr` to create a 3-column wide grid, where the first and last columns take up equal amounts of available space. 
This can be thought of similarly to applying `flex: 1` to `.header__left` and `.header__right`.

The nice thing about this approach is that the icon to the left and brand logo will keep their position even if the container for the right-aligned button is removed, either by removing the HTML element completely or by using `display: none`.

**SCSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;

    &__left,
    &__middle,
    &__right {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    &__left {
        background: orange;
        justify-content: flex-end;

        /* You can either apply padding to .header__left or 
           .header__middle to separate the icon from the 
           brand logo. */
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }

    &__middle {
        background: green;

        /* This isn't really needed since this container's 
           column width is set to auto. */
        justify-content: center;
    }

    &__right {
        background: red;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
}

.header__icon {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    background: blue;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.header__left, 
.header__middle, 
.header__right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__left {
  background: orange;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.header__middle {
  background: green;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__right {
  background: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header__icon {
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <icon-base class="header__icon" width="46" height="46" icon-name="brands">
      <brands />
    </icon-base>
  </div>
  <div class="header__middle">
    <h2 class="header__text">Brand App</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="header__right">
    <button>Some button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As mentioned above, removing `.header__right` element completely or using `display: none` will not affect the positioning of the other containers.

**Removing the HTML element completely**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khan_y/pnjq3hm5/6/)

**Using `display: none` on `.header__right`**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khan_y/vzf38w4r/1/)

Comment: That's almost perfect, I found out that what breaks my spacing is when the words wraps on two lines. In this case the title container (header__middle) becomes bigger the icon is too far from the icon. How could I deal with that ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by *"the icon is too far from the icon"*. Could you update your question with either an image or example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Whoops I meant the icon was too far from the title, but I managed to fix it :) Thanks for help